# Center image vertically between header and bottom of window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image of a phone vertically. The code I have to far works but if I decrease the window height the phone image will overlap the header. What I want to do is center the phone image vertically between the bottom of the header and the bottom of the window and stay there no matter how tall the window is (but not overlap the header).

Link to jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zAMDokl6RG.

Having lots of issues with this. Could someone give me some pointers on how to do this please? Thanks :

**css:**

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   /* To keep our header correct */
 }
 #header {
   background: #e9e6e6;
   /* Here set your colour */
   height: 55px;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   /* box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;*/
 }
 .innerdiv {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 0px 0px;
   z-index: -2;
 }
 .dllogodiv {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 5px 5px;
 }
 .centeredImage {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
 }
 .centeredImage img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">My header</div>
</div>


<div class="innerdiv">
  <img class="imageCorner" src="http://s4.postimg.org/tyfx93u8p/logo.png">
</div>
<p class="centeredImage">
  <img src="http://s4.postimg.org/p12cnzs9l/slide1.png">
</p>
```

Comment: Fiddle: Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page

Comment: jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zAMDokl6RG

Comment: @KexAri try the link you keep pasting, it does not work.  Also what's with the logo - what's it meant to do?

Comment: The logo just sits in the bottom right corner (that's not the actual logo). I keep trying to put that code into a fiddle and it works for me but seems if someone tries to join it either doesn't show the code for them or the page just isn't there

Comment: anyway the fiddle is just the exact code posted here

Comment: Any reason you are using absolute positioning? it will become a nightmare to keep track of all your elements and z-indexs

Comment: @Pete Complete newbie at this so just using what I found when researching

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/oLht7mx6/

Comment: @Pete works! only issue is the logo in the bottom right isn't quite at the bottom very small gap

Comment: I just added "block" to the logo in the right it's perfect now. Thanks you so much!

Comment: @Pete Put that in an answer so I can +1 it already. Shame I can't do a +2 for not doing the whole "Yu iz needings t3h `display:flex;`"

Answer (score 1):

[heres a fiddle I put together](https://jsfiddle.net/e6poka4e/2/)

the idea is to have a top/middle/bottom. There is a css `calc` property you can use to calculate something, like height. Assuming you know what the height of your image is (lets say 200px), you can do:

```
top: calc(50% - 100px);
```

this will make the top of your image 50% from the top, minus half the size of the image, so that the middle of the image is 50% from the top.

of course, you have to set the middle section to `position relative or absolute`, and make the `image position absolute` inside.

This is just one quick way, there are other ways. Then again, usually you want to center something within a div, not the whole page.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take a look. Got it working with the code above but I'll try and follow through with your explanation.